# Can't create text box dynamically and retrieve value in the same postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I am trying to create Text Box controls dynamically at the user's request.

The problem is that I can't, in the same postback, both create the dynamic textbox and retrieve
the number that the user entered, and use that to create the other text boxes.

It seems that I'm always one postback behind.

That's the entire code in my example and I have no other code in the HTML page.

Please help my fix the problem so i could create the number of textboxes the user requested at the moment he requested them.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        form1.InnerText = "how many TextBoxes would you like to add?";
        form1.InnerHtml += "<br />";

        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "TextBox1";
        tb.Attributes.Add("type", "number");
        tb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        tb.Attributes.Add("min", "1");
        tb.Attributes.Add("max", "5");                
        tb.AutoPostBack = true;
        tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
        form1.Controls.Add(tb);

        if (tb.Text != "")
        {            
            for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(tb.Text); i++)
            {
                TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
                tb1.ID = "newTB" + i.ToString();
                form1.Controls.Add(tb1);
            }     
        }                    
    }

    protected void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

I tried writing the shortest and simplest of codes as i'm only interested in figuring out the principle that stands behind my problem, and I couldn't find a question similar enough to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so your code isn't following standard asp.net coding practises. The following is a simple working example of what you are trying to achieve:

**Form Code**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">How many textboxes would you like to create?</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Invalid Number" MaximumValue="5" 
            MinimumValue="1"></asp:RangeValidator>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text); i++)
            {
                TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
                tb1.ID = "newTB" + i.ToString();
                form1.Controls.Add(tb1);
            }
        }   
    }
```

I'd really recommend reading up on the asp.net page [lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and working through some basic examples to understand the fundamental principles. This [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/) is a good place to start.

**Edit - Revised**: Below is another stab at your question, again needs a bit love and refactoring (and I'm sure there may be better ways of doing this!) but it works. In my test form I had a submit button and it the created textboxes then 'retained' their value between postbacks (but they are actually being recreated from the Request).

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (string key in Request.Form)
        {
            if (key.StartsWith("newTB"))
            {
                TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
                tb1.ID = key;
                tb1.Text = Request.Form[key];
                form1.Controls.Add(tb1);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label1 = new Label()
        {
            ID = "label1",
            Text = "How many textboxes would you like to create?"
        };

    form1.Controls.Add(label1);

    TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox()
        {
            ID = "TextBox1",
            AutoPostBack = true,
            CausesValidation = true
        };

    textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextBox1_TextChanged);

    form1.Controls.Add(textBox1);

    RangeValidator rangeValidator = new RangeValidator()
        {
            ID="RangeValidator1",
            ControlToValidate = "TextBox1",
            MaximumValue = "5",
            ErrorMessage = "Out of range!",
            MinimumValue = "1"
        };

    form1.Controls.Add(rangeValidator);
}

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = form1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;

    if (Page.IsValid && textBox.Text != "")
    {
        RemoveOldControls();

        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(textBox.Text); i++)
        {
            TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
            tb1.ID = "newTB" + i.ToString();
            form1.Controls.Add(tb1);
        }
    }
}

//Recursive method to remove all "newTB" textboxes
private void RemoveOldControls()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < form1.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(form1.Controls[i].ID) && form1.Controls[i].ID.StartsWith("newTB"))
        {
            TextBox newTextBox = form1.Controls[i] as TextBox;

            if (newTextBox != null)
                form1.Controls.Remove(newTextBox);

            RemoveOldControls();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Damon,
Thank you very much for answering. I knew i wasn't following standard asp.net coding practices but the whole point was to do it all dynamically. I know how to do it the way you did it. I would really like to know if it's possible to do it all dynamically and how?

Comment: @michael, just updated my answer, hope that helps. Haven't tested it thoroughly but that should at least demonstrate the concept. There's plenty of stuff to read up on things like this on the web :)

Comment: Thank you for your rapid Reply but unfortunately i tried doing something  very similar myself and i encountered the same problem. The text boxes that were created dynamically don't hold their values after post back and i can't store them and use them later in my code.
Again i am really thankful for your help.

Comment: Ahhh, that is a bit more complicated. If I get round to it, I'll see if I can put something together tomorrow.

Comment: I really do appreciate all of your help but unfortunately your revised code didn't retain the value of the text boxes either.

Comment: Strange, seems to fine on my side. Oh well.

Comment: The code you posted is all of the code you used?
You said something about a submit button but i tested your code "as is". On text change a post back accrues and new text boxes are created but the value in them still isn't retained across post backs.

Comment: Yeah, just with a standard <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /> in the page to cause the PostBack. In the page load the Request is examined and the controls are recreated and have their values reset. If you set a breakpoint in the page_load event you should be able to watch this all happen.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps you.

```
public partial class SomeClass
{
    private TextBox _textBox;
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _textBox = new TextBox { EnableViewState = true };
        _textBox.TextChanged += (o, args) =>
                                    {

                                    };
        Wrapper.Controls.Add(_textBox);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            _textBox.Text = "Initial Text";
        }
        else
        {
            // Loaded from viewstate, yay.
        }
    }
}

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Wrapper"/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="PostBack!"/>
</asp:Content>
```

You should always add dynamic controls within the Page_Init.

Here is what I have tested:

- Code (in debug) breaks in the Page_Init, Page_Load
- "Initial Text" has been set to the textbox in the Page_Load.
- I change the text to "Initial Text123"
- I click the button which causes a PostBack
- Code (in debug) breaks in the Page_init, Page_Load, TextChanged handler.
- I can see that the textbox contains text "Initial Text123" as soon as i'm in the Page_Load, because it has reloaded from it's values from the ViewState.

Comment: Your answer did help me but not completely. If i want to create new text boxes according to the value in the first text box i simply add that code to the Page_Load function in your answer. 
But if i want to create dynamically other controls according to the values in these text boxes (the new ones) i can't because i won't have access to the new values. My end goal is to create dynamically controls have the user insert values(integers) in to those controls and create new controls according to those values.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your issue? I have been thinking about this trying to find a neat solution but haven't gotten the time to code anything